# Fade out in ffmpeg when creating a video from a still image is wonky?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm creating a video that:

- uses a still image as a source
- has a text overlay
- fades in and out
- has a silent stereo audio track.

So far, I have this, and it (almost) works correctly:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "aevalsrc=0|0" -loop 1 -i turtle-2.jpg  -c:v libx264 -t 5 -r 30 -s 1920x1080 -aspect 16:9 -pix_fmt yuv420p -filter:v drawtext="fontsize=130:fontfile=comic.ttf:text='hello world':x=(w-text_w)*.25:y=(h-text_h)*.75",fade=in:0:60,fade=out:90:60 -acodec aac turtle11.mp4
```

The only problem is that the fade out doesn't seem to be going to black, even tho this is a 150 frame video and I believe I am following the [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-Examples-53) correctly.

The resulting video is here:

http://video.blivenyc.com/vid-from-image/turtle11.mp4

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure why but this works, even tho it appears to be equivalent:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "aevalsrc=0|0" -loop 1 -i turtle-2.jpg  -c:v libx264 -t 5 -r 30 -s 1920x1080 -aspect 16:9 -pix_fmt yuv420p -filter:v drawtext="fontsize=130:fontfile=comic.ttf:text='hello world':x=(w-text_w)*.25:y=(h-text_h)*.75",fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1 -acodec aac turtle12.mp4
```

Basically, frame-based syntax:

fade=in:0:60,fade=out:90:60

gets substitued with time-based:

fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1

And somehow it works. Not sure why this is.

Answer (score 0):

The video stream on which the fade filter operates is not 150 frames long. Input and output framerates are different here. The use of `-r` to set output rate happens after all filtering is done. At that stage, ffmpeg will drop or duplicate frames to obtain the output rate.

The input rate for an image or image sequence is 25, unless expressly set otherwise. In your command, since there is no override, it's 25. So fade out of 60 frames starting at frame 90, will end at frame 125 (5 seconds x 25). ffmpeg will duplicate 5 frames of each input second to get it to 30.

To get the desired result, use

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "aevalsrc=0|0" -loop 1 -framerate 30 -i turtle-2.jpg  -c:v libx264 -t 5 -s 1920x1080 -aspect 16:9 -pix_fmt yuv420p -filter:v drawtext="fontsize=130:fontfile=comic.ttf:text='hello world':x=(w-text_w)*.25:y=(h-text_h)*.75",fade=in:0:60,fade=out:90:60 -acodec aac turtle11.mp4
```